# Eigenvalues of a matrix with binomial entries

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to determine the eigenvalues of the following matrix:

$$M_{ij} = 4^{-j}\binom{2j}{i}$$

where it is understood that the binomial coefficient $\binom{m}{k}$ is zero if $k<0$ or $k>m$. Here $i,j$ go from $0$ to $N$, therefore the matrix is $(N+1)\times(N+1)$.

If an exact expression is not available, I would content myself with approximations valid for large $N$.

Moreover, I am mostly interested in the largest positive eigenvalue and its corresponding eigenvector.

Comment: Maybe the point of view of polynomials could be useful here.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Can you expand?

Comment: Consider the basis $\left\{1,X,\dots,X^n\right\}$. Then $M$ is the matrix of the linear map which sets $X^j$ to $\sum_{i\leqslant \min\left(2j,n\right)}4^{-j}\binom{2j}{i}X^i$. If $2j\leqslant n$, we have $4^{-j}\left(1+X\right)^{2 j}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly 1 is an eigenvalue for the eigenvector $(1,0,\dots,0)$.

On the other hand it is the largest eigenvalue, since the 1-norm of the operator corresponding to the matrix is 1. In fact, (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm)
$$
\|M\|_1=\sup_{\|x\|>0}\frac{\|M(x)\|_1}{\|x\|_1}=\max_{0\le j\le N}\sum_{i=0}^N|M_{ij}|=1
$$ 
The last equality follows from the fact that the equality is attained for $j=0$ and in general
$$
\sum_{i=0}^N|M_{ij}|\le \sum_{i=0}^{2j}|M_{ij}|=\frac{1}{2^{2j}}\sum_{i=0}^{2j}\binom{2j}{i}=1
$$

The absolute value of an eigenvalue cannot be greater than $\|M\|_1=1$, since
$$
|\lambda|\|x\|_1=\|Mx\|_1\le \|M\|_1\|x\|_1=\|x\|_1.
$$