# Eigenvalues of a truncated matrix with binomial entries

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, binomial-coefficients

This question is closely related to [Eigenvalues of a matrix with binomial entries](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2349347/10063), but is a bit more general.

I am trying to determine the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the following matrix:

$$M_{ij} = 4^{-j}\binom{2j}{i}$$

where it is understood that the binomial coefficient $\binom{m}{k}$ is zero if $k<0$ or $k>m$. The indices $i,j$ traverse a discrete finite range, $i,j \in \{a, a+1, \dots, b\}$, from $a$ to $b$, where $a,b$ are non-negative integers with $0\le a\le b$ (this is the difference to the previous question). Therefore the matrix $M_{ij}$ has dimensions $(b-a+1) \times (b-a+1)$.

I would content myself with an approximate expression (if there is no exact analytical result), valid for large $a,b$. I am mostly interested in the largest eigenvalue (*not* in absolute value, but the largest positive eigenvalue) and the corresponding eigenvector.

Also a recurrence relation would be useful. Anything that helps...

To be explicit, we want to solve the following eigenquation:

$$\sum_{j=a}^b 4^{-j} \binom{2j}{i} x_j = \lambda x_i,\quad i=a, a+1, ..., b$$

for the eigenvalues $\lambda$ and eigenvectors $x_i$.

**Update:** Numerical experiments *suggest* that if $a,b\rightarrow \infty$ with a fixed ratio $a/b$, the largest eigenvalue $\rightarrow 1$ always, irrespective of the value of the ratio $a/b$. There is a leading order correction proportional to $1/\sqrt{b}$, and the value of the proportionality constant depends on the value of the ratio $a/b$. I do not know how to prove any of these statements, and I cannot be sure they are correct. It would be nice if we could compute the value of leading order coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 2017-07-26.

We have
$$
\sum_{j=a}^b 4^{-j} \binom{2j}{i} x_j = \lambda x_i
$$
This is declared for $i=a, a+1, ..., b$.

Suppose we have found $\lambda$ and the $\{x_i \}, i=a, a+1, \dots, b$ through these equations. Let us then use the same equation for obtaining further  $x_i, i=0, \dots, a-1$ and  $x_i, i=b+1, \dots, 2b$.

Now  apply to both sides, for arbitrary $q$, 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{2 b} q^i \; (\cdot)
$$
This gives for the LHS
$$
\sum_{j=a}^b 4^{-j} x_j \sum_{i=0}^{2 b} \binom{2j}{i} q^i =\\
\sum_{j=a}^b 4^{-j} x_j \sum_{i=0}^{2 j} \binom{2j}{i} q^i 1^{2 j - i} = \\
\sum_{j=a}^b 4^{-j} x_j (1+q)^{2j}
$$
On the RHS, we have that the $x_i$ outside the $[a,b]$-range are obtained by the additional equations as introduced above. So we have
 for all $q$ for the extended set of unknowns $x_i ;  i=0, 1, ..., 2b$ and $\lambda$ :
$$
\sum_{j=a}^b x_j (\frac{1+q}{2})^{2j} = \lambda \sum_{j=0}^{2b}  x_j q^j
$$

So, applying different $q$, we have a set of polynomial equations from which to deduce the  $\{x_i \}, i=0, 1, \dots, 2b$ as well as $\lambda$. I cannot directly see how to solve those.

Some examples are:

$$
q\to 0: \quad \sum_{j=a}^b 4^{-j} x_j  = \lambda \; x_0
$$

$$
q = 1: \quad \sum_{j=a}^b  x_j  = \lambda \sum_{j=0}^{2b}  x_j 
$$

$$
q\to \infty: \quad  (\frac{q}{2})^{2b}  x_b  = \lambda  \, x_{2b} \, q^{2b} \quad {\mathrm{; i.e.}} \quad 4^{-b}  x_b  = \lambda \, x_{2b} 
$$

The last one can also be seen directly from the original equations. From them, 
one can deduce for example for $i = 2b-1$:
$$
\sum_{j=a}^b 4^{-j} \binom{2j}{2b-1} x_j = \lambda \, x_{2b - 1} \quad {\mathrm{; i.e.}} \quad  2 b \, 4^{-b}  x_b  = \lambda \, x_{2b -1} 
$$
and for $i = 2b-2$:
$$
\sum_{j=a}^b 4^{-j} \binom{2j}{2b-2} x_j = \lambda \, x_{2b - 2} \quad {\mathrm{; i.e.}} \quad   4^{-b} \binom{2b}{2b-2} x_b  +  4^{-b-1}  x_{b -1} = \lambda \, x_{2b -2} 
$$

This sets the path for iteratively determining the  additional $x_i, i=b+1, \dots, 2b$.

Hope someone else can help for a complete solution.

Comment: +1 Brilliant! Very nice approach. Let's see we can squeeze something more out of it.

Comment: However something is fishy ... the eigenvalue for finite $a<b$ is not 1. I cannot find the error though... and I hope that the generating function technique can be applied nonetheless .... please even if it happens to be wrong do not delete it.

Comment: If $x_i = 0$ for $i < a$, then the equality does not hold for those items, and you cannot include them in the sum without breaking the equation.

Comment: Yes you are right with your last comment. However, one might still expand the argument. Please see main text.

Comment: Yes, please don't delete this. The generating function approach could be useful.

Comment: Your approach also implies that the eigenvalues are non-degenerate: For a given $\lambda$ there can be at most one $x_i$ (up to a constant factor)... You can also arrange the terms so that on the LHS you always have smaller indices and on the RHS larger indices, which is kind of a recurrence relation ... that you cannot really solve because you do not know $\lambda$, but it's something... :)

Comment: And it also shows that all the eigenvalues are positive!

Comment: I was going to award the bounty to you (even though the solution is incomplete) because I think this is the more promising approach. I was waiting a bit more time to see if someone else stepped up. But now it expired while I was offline, I am sorry!

Comment: Dear becko, thanks a  lot anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I will give only a bound for the eigenvalues based on the 1-norm $\|-\|_1$ of $M$
defined by
$$
\|M\|_1=\sup_{\|x\|>0}\frac{\|M(x)\|_1}{\|x\|_1}=\max_{1\le j\le n}\sum_{i=1}^n|M_{ij}|
$$

We have 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n|M_{ij}|= \sum_{i=a}^{b}\frac{1}{2^{2j}}\binom{2j}{i}\le \sum_{i=0}^{2j}\frac{1}{2^{2j}}\binom{2j}{i}=1
$$
and if $a>0$, then the inequality is strict, and if $a=0$, then we have equality.

Moreover, the absolute values of eigenvalues are bounded by $|\lambda|\le \|M\|_1$, since
$$
|\lambda|\|x\|_1=\|Mx\|_1\le \|M\|_1\|x\|_1.
$$

So in general we have for an eigenvalue $\lambda$:
$$
|\lambda|\le \|M\|_1=\max_{a\le j\le b}\sum_{i=a}^{b}\frac{1}{2^{2j}}\binom{2j}{i}.
$$

For big $a,b$ the binomial distribution given by $\frac{1}{2^{2j}}\binom{2j}{i}$ can be approximated by the Gauss normal curve with expected value $j$ and variation $\sigma^2=j/2$, and so

$$
\|M\|_1\approx \max_{t\in[a,b]}\int_{a}^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}}e^{-\frac{(s-t)^2}{t}}ds.
$$

This explains (or at least does not contradict) the fact that 
for big $a$, $b$, the largest eigenvalue tends to 1, since for constant ratio
$a/b$, the value of the integral for $t=(a+b)/2$ is near 1, since the interval $[a,b]$ contains several lengths of the standard variation $\sigma=\sqrt{t/2}$.

Comment: Could we somehow make the argument that $\lambda \approx ||M||_1$ for large $a,b$?

Comment: I tried several approaches, but I came almost empty. One can try to prove that all eigenvalues are different and positive (in particular they are real). Numerical evidence suggest this. Then it would suffice to prove that $\|M\|_2$ tends to 1, for large $a,b$, since then $\|M\|_2=\lambda_{max}$.

Comment: I can show that all the eigenvalues are distinct and positive using generating functions (the approach of Andreas). Can we also show *how* $\lambda_\max$ tends to 1? That is, find the asymptotics, at least to first order.

Comment: Note that my answers shows that $\|M\|_1$ tends to 1, not that $\|M\|_2$ tends to 1. In order to prove the asymptotics for $\|M\|_2$, maybe it suffices to look at the first column and its image (there is no nice formula for this).

Comment: Maybe these inequalities are of some help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Examples_of_norm_equivalence.